# Black body radiation curiosity

Tags: thermodynamics

Wich one of the two cases will be more suitable
A hotter body for instance candle with its flame with the pic in infrared region of emissivity will emit more microwave radiation or a colder one with its pic in microwave region as we know that both bodies emits trhough all the spectrum because of blackbody radiation principle. Please explain why.

Answer (score 3):

A hotter black body emits more radiation than a colder black body at **all** wavelengths. The hotter body will have the peak of its spectrum at a shorter wavelength, but it outshines the colder body everywhere.

The intensity of the radiation from a black body is given by:

$$ B(\lambda,T) = \frac{2\pi hc^2}{\lambda^5}\frac{1}{\exp\left(\frac{hc}{k_bT\lambda}\right)-1} $$

If you consider a constant wavelength then as the temperature increases the factor of $\exp\left(\frac{hc}{k_bT\lambda}\right)$ decreases towards one, so $\exp\left(\frac{hc}{k_bT\lambda}\right) - 1$ tends to zero and $1/\left(\exp\left(\frac{hc}{k_bT\lambda}\right) - 1\right)$ tends to infinity. That means at all wavelengths the radiated power increases with temperature. The hotter body will radiate more power at microwave wavelengths even though its peak radiation may be at much shorter wavelengths.